# RTC control register change by itself after GetRTC and SetRTC

Tags: stm32

Now I would like to use my STM32L462 RTC for use in project.
Initially, I set format time to HourFormat 24 (FMT = 0)
https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0351-stm32l47xxx-stm32l48xxx-stm32l49xxx-and-stm32l4axxx-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf

However, After I try to retrieve RTC value and set RTC value. RTC->CR is change which is include FMT bit
[as this result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdKNW.png)

I would like to know that they will be prevent from FMT bit to change from using `HAL_GetRTC` and `HAL_SetRTC` ?

Here below is a part of my code:
**SetRTC**

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef SetRTC(uint64_t epoch)
{
    status = HAL_BUSY;
//  PRINT_DEBUG_YELLOW_LN("SetRTC");

    char debug_msg[64];
    time_t rawtime = (time_t)epoch;
    RTC_TimeTypeDef sTime;
    RTC_DateTypeDef sDate;

    //Convert epoch to RTC
    struct tm* time_tm;
    time_tm = gmtime(&rawtime);

    sTime.Hours = (uint8_t)time_tm->tm_hour;
    sTime.Minutes = (uint8_t)time_tm->tm_min;
    sTime.Seconds = (uint8_t)time_tm->tm_sec;
    if (time_tm->tm_wday == 0) { time_tm->tm_wday = 7; } // the chip goes mon tue wed thu fri sat sun
    sDate.WeekDay = (uint8_t)time_tm->tm_wday;
    sDate.Month = (uint8_t)time_tm->tm_mon+1; //momth 1- This is why date math is frustrating.
    sDate.Date = (uint8_t)time_tm->tm_mday;
    sDate.Year = (uint16_t)(time_tm->tm_year+1900-2000); // time.h is years since 1900, chip is years since 2000

    //Set RTC
//  HAL_RTC_Init(&hrtc);
    status = HAL_RTC_SetDate(&hrtc, &sDate, RTC_FORMAT_BIN);
//  if(status != HAL_OK);
//      return status;

    status = HAL_RTC_SetTime(&hrtc, &sTime, RTC_FORMAT_BIN);
//  if(status != HAL_OK);
//      return status;

    sprintf(debug_msg,"Clock Set to %d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d (%ld)", (2000+sDate.Year),sDate.Month,sDate.Date,sTime.Hours,sTime.Minutes,sTime.Seconds,(uint32_t)epoch);
    PRINT_DEBUG_LN(debug_msg);

    status = HAL_OK;
    return status;
}
```

**GetRTC**

```
uint64_t GetRTC(void)
{
//  PRINT_DEBUG_YELLOW_LN("GetRTC");

    char debug_msg[64];
    RTC_TimeTypeDef currentTime;
    RTC_DateTypeDef currentDate;
    time_t timestamp;
    struct tm currTime;

//  HAL_RTC_Init(&hrtc);

    HAL_RTC_GetTime(&hrtc, &currentTime, RTC_FORMAT_BIN);
    HAL_RTC_GetDate(&hrtc, &currentDate, RTC_FORMAT_BIN);

    currTime.tm_year = currentDate.Year + 100;  // In fact: 2000 + 18 - 1900
    currTime.tm_mday = currentDate.Date;
    currTime.tm_mon  = currentDate.Month - 1;

    currTime.tm_hour = currentTime.Hours;
    currTime.tm_min  = currentTime.Minutes;
    currTime.tm_sec  = currentTime.Seconds;

    timestamp = (uint64_t)(mktime(&currTime));

//  PRINT_DEBUG_GREEN_LN("-->OK");
    sprintf(debug_msg,"From RTC Options: %08lx",RTC->CR);
    PRINT_DEBUG_LN(debug_msg);
    sprintf(debug_msg,"From RTC: %08lx %08lx",RTC->DR,RTC->TR);
    PRINT_DEBUG_LN(debug_msg);
    sprintf(debug_msg,"From RTC: %d %d %d %d %d %d", currentDate.Year,currentDate.Month,currentDate.Date,currentTime.Hours,currentTime.Minutes,currentTime.Seconds);
    PRINT_DEBUG_LN(debug_msg);
    sprintf(debug_msg,"Current time is %d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d (%ld)", (1900+currTime.tm_year),currTime.tm_mon+1,currTime.tm_mday,currTime.tm_hour,currTime.tm_min,currTime.tm_sec,(uint32_t)timestamp);
    PRINT_DEBUG_LN(debug_msg);

    return timestamp;
}
```

**MX_RTC_Init**

```
/* RTC init function */
void MX_RTC_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 0 */

  RTC_TimeTypeDef sTime = {0};
  RTC_DateTypeDef sDate = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 1 */
  /** Initialize RTC Only
  */
  hrtc.Instance = RTC;
  hrtc.Init.HourFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT_24;
  hrtc.Init.AsynchPrediv = 127;
  hrtc.Init.SynchPrediv = 255;
  hrtc.Init.OutPut = RTC_OUTPUT_DISABLE;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutRemap = RTC_OUTPUT_REMAP_NONE;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutPolarity = RTC_OUTPUT_POLARITY_HIGH;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutType = RTC_OUTPUT_TYPE_OPENDRAIN;
  if (HAL_RTC_Init(&hrtc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Check_RTC_BKUP */
  return;
  /* USER CODE END Check_RTC_BKUP */

  /** Initialize RTC and set the Time and Date
  */
  sTime.Hours = 0;
  sTime.Minutes = 0;
  sTime.Seconds = 0;
  sTime.DayLightSaving = RTC_DAYLIGHTSAVING_NONE;
  sTime.StoreOperation = RTC_STOREOPERATION_RESET;
  if (HAL_RTC_SetTime(&hrtc, &sTime, RTC_FORMAT_BIN) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sDate.WeekDay = RTC_WEEKDAY_MONDAY;
  sDate.Month = RTC_MONTH_JANUARY;
  sDate.Date = 1;
  sDate.Year = 0;

  if (HAL_RTC_SetDate(&hrtc, &sDate, RTC_FORMAT_BIN) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 2 */

}
```

Comment: Why do you have `HAL_RTC_Init` in `SetRTC` and `GetRTC`? That may be the reason why the configuration is changing. Do you still have the problem with the `HAL_RTC_Init` commented out?

Comment: Yes, It still have even ```HAL_RTC_Init``` commented out. Honestly, I tried to keep config back to original by using ```HAL_RTC_Init``` but I was thinking that not the point to solve.

Comment: You should try to minimize the code to the smallest possible form that still has your problem. For example, remove commented out code, all debug related code (like print). Remove calls to `mktime` and `gmtime` and try to set the date/time with zero-initialized structs.

Comment: I already remove it unless of ```HAL_RTC_GetTime(&hrtc, &currentTime, RTC_FORMAT_BIN);
    HAL_RTC_GetDate(&hrtc, &currentDate, RTC_FORMAT_BIN);``` and ```status = HAL_RTC_SetDate(&hrtc, &sDate, RTC_FORMAT_BIN); status = HAL_RTC_SetTime(&hrtc, &sTime, RTC_FORMAT_BIN);```. It still changed but defense number (RTC->CR: 0x0100 F778). I also curious why when I burn new program. Register should reset to ZERO but when debug it start with other number. Is it a way to reset RTC_CR to zero?

Comment: Well, the functions you mention do not change the CR register, so something else must be going on. Do you have RTC backup battery? If so, try to remove it to reset the CR register.

Comment: Thank you @Armandas is seems options byte is get back to zero but I still confused that why it happen and why software reset does not reset RTC->CR to zero. I may test about few hours to check it.